# How can I replace my Nexus 5's broken screen?

Tags: screen, nexus-5

So I have the Nexus 5 and unfortunately I drop it and my screen shatter, does anyone knows where or of there's a place where I can send it to get it replace... Also how easy it is to replace? I would like to try to do it myself if it is possible.

Answer (score 2):

First, try to contact [Google and/or LG](https://support.google.com/googleplay/troubleshooter/3070579?hl=en#ts=3070585,3457226).  If they determine that warranty doesn't cover this, their own repair service might not be as expensive, compared to buying the parts and swapping the screen on your own.

If you are not comfortable with taking apart and putting back together small electronics, I would advise against doing it yourself, as you may end up accidentally damaging the replacement parts, thus wasting your money. See if there are any local electronics repair shops that can do it for you instead. They may cost slightly more, but at least they will have more experience with phones.

If you do decide to go the Do-It-Yourself route, there are many [guides](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5vxXdzQ2p8k) and [walk-through](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jQS618ayL5w) [videos](http://www.etradesupply.com/blog/how-to-repair-nexus-5-cracked-screen/) available with a simple [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=nexus%205%20screen%20replacement%20video).  The parts themselves are also [easily](http://www.etradesupply.com/lg/android-models/lg-nexus-5.html) [found](http://www.amazon.com/s/?ie=UTF8&keywords=nexus%205%20screen%20replacement&tag=googhydr-20&index=aps&hvadid=31728434916&hvpos=1t1&hvexid=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=12377521611353817772&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=b&hvdev=c&ref=pd_sl_8td6egprsv_b) using [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=nexus%205%20screen%20replacement%20kit).  Keep in mind that depending on the damage, you may need to buy the LCD with digitizer combination, as opposed to only the glass panel.